# Position Bias Normalization in CTR Prediction

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction, normalization

I am working on **Click Through Rate(CTR)** prediction model on a toy dataset.
The label I am using is **`#Click/#NumShown`**.

But there is **position bias** in **results shown**. For e.g.: result shown on **top** will generally **get more click** than results shown **below** it.

My question is, **what should be the ideal way to normalize clicks(label) for all positions?**

Comment: Here you go: http://wan.poly.edu/KDD2012/docs/p795.pdf . What you want is position normalized clicks over expected clicks.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: wan.poly.edu link is dead. use http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/cip/liukang.files/kddcup2012.pdf